# Understanding the Eilenberg-Zilber map on singular chains

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, simplex, simplicial-stuff

I am having trouble to understand how the image of an element $a\otimes b\in C_p(X)\otimes C_q(Y)$ under the Eilenberg-Zilber map on singular chains is an element of $C_{p+q}(X\times Y)$.

I am using the explicit expression of the map given in [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eilenberg-Zilber+map) which works in general for any simplicial abelian group, or the one in page 7 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110308.pdf) given under the name of EML operator for normalized chains.

So, let $\Delta^n$ be the simplex of dimension $n$ and consider the degenerancy maps $s^i:\Delta^n\to\Delta^{n-1}$. Let $a:\Delta^p\to X$ and $b:\Delta^q\to Y$. We may define degenerancy maps $s_i:C_{p}(X)\to C_{p+1}(X)$ by $s_i(a)=a\circ s^i$. Now, up to sign, when I apply the Eilenberg-Zilber map to $a\otimes b$ I get

$$\sum_{(\mu, \nu)}s_\nu(a)\times s_\mu(b)$$

where $(\mu,\nu)$ are $(p,q)$-[shuffles](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shuffle) and $s_\mu$ is a composition of degenerancy maps. Let me do an example so show my problem with this definition.

Let $a:[0,1]\to X$ and $b:[0,1]\to Y$ two 1-simplices. There are two $(1,1)$-shuffles which are the 2 permutations of $S_2$. Therefore, there are only two degenerancy maps to take into account, $s_0$ and $s_1$.The Eilenberg-Zilber map here is

$$\nabla(a\otimes b)=s_1(a)\times s_0(b)-s_0(a)\times s_1(b)$$

My problem is that a chain in $C_{p+q}(X\times Y)$ should be a map $\Delta^{p+q}\to X\times Y$, which in this example means $\Delta^2\to X\times Y$. But for instance in this case, $s_1(a)=a\circ s^1: \Delta^2\to\Delta^1\to X$ and similarly $s_0(b):\Delta^2\to Y$, so what I get is a map $\Delta^2\times\Delta^2\to X\times Y$, so how exactly is this map an element of $C_2(X\times Y)$ or more generaly of $C_{p+q}(X\times Y)$?

Comment: I'm seeing some $\times$ where I'd expect an $\otimes$...

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer in the second reference I see $\times$, and the $\otimes$ in the nlab is for a general simplicial abelian group. What is $\Delta^2\otimes\Delta^2$ then?

Comment: Hmm. So, if I imagine the special case of two $1$-simplices, then the product of two maps $\Delta^1 \to X$ and $\Delta^1 \to Y$ is a map $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \to X \times Y$. Now you would like a map $\Delta^2 \to X$, but $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1$ isn't $\Delta^2$. However, it's quite close: you can triangulate it in that you can split up in two triangles in a natural way. There is a natural higher-dimensional generalisation of this triangulation, which I know is where the triangulation should intuitively come from.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer yes, I know, and originally I thought that each summand would be a map from each of the inclusions $\Delta^2\subset\Delta^1\times\Delta^1$, but $s_i(a)$ has $\Delta^2$ as domain, so it doesn't look like $s_1(a)\times s_0(b)$ has $\Delta^1\times\Delta^1$ as domain, but rather $\Delta^2\times\Delta^2$.

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding something about the degenerancies or about how the map is defined, because I believe the spirit of the definition is what you said.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit confused too by the formulas. I'm taking a look at Hatcher (p. 277--278) which has a more wordy definition of what is essentially the Eilenberg--Zilber formula. I'm hoping that it gives some insights in what was supposed to be meant.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Thank you I'll have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$, $X$ and $Y$ be spaces. Then a map $A \to X \times Y$ is the same as the data of a map $A \to X$ and a map $A \to Y$; that is, it is uniquely determined by its components.

When you see the expression $s_\nu(a) \times s_\nu(b)$, you should read this as a map with domain $\Delta^{p+q}$ and codomain $X \times Y$, whose first coordinate is given by the map $s_\nu(a)$ and second coordinate is given by the map $s_\nu(b)$.

To be honest, this formula hides a lot of intuitive content. To me, the Eilenberg-Zilber map is: "Send $\Delta^p \otimes \Delta^q$ to the canonical triangulation of $\Delta^p \times \Delta^q$." The elements in your sum each correspond to a simplex in said triangulation.

This question was asked 5 months ago so I imagine you have now resolved whatever confusions you had, or moved on. But if you are still hoping to understand this, I *strongly* recommend trying to see "why" the formula above describes the standard triangulation of $\Delta^2 \times \Delta^1$. This gave me more intuition for the Eilenberg-Zilber map than anything else ever has.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is helpful. I held on the intuition and sometimes I used Hatcher's definition. I'll try to think why the formula gives the triangulation, I have an idea but it is hard to see formally.